# How to get info: The Author/his Comments for the last subversion revision via command line?

Tags: svn, logging, comments, author

I can't seem to find this one!

So say someone like "Joe" (the Author) submits his code into the svn repository with the message "Fixed this bug and that bug yada yada" (his Comments).

I'd like to get, via the svn.exe command line, the Author and his Comments for the latest revision.
Maybe someone can tell me what arguments I could use to achieve this?? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

The following command will show you information on the latest commit to the svn repository (revision, contributor, date and time, and message):

```
svn log [PATH] -r HEAD
```

If you want to find the last commit for the given path/project/file then:

```
svn log [PATH] -l 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The command is

```
svn log
```

The -l [Number] flag is useful, it limits the number of revisions you're shown.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [svn log](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re15.html) is what you are looking for. Also, [svn info](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re13.html) for more information.